# Reading credentials from XML and initialize variables

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to read credentials from xml and initialize to private variables using php.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<config>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <username>Jani</username>
    <password>1234r</password>
</config>
```

I am using following class and constructor to initialize variables.

```
<?php

class Admin {

    public $host = "";
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $table;
    private $crendentials = array();

    public function __construct() {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("config.xml");

    foreach ($this->crendentials as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == $this->host) {
            $this->host = $value;
        } elseif ($key == $this->username) {
            $this->username = $value;
        } elseif ($key == $this->password) {
            $this->password = $value;
        }
    }


    foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
        $this->crendentials[$child->getName()] = $child;
    }
}

public function getHost() {
    print_r($this->crendentials);
    echo $this->host;
    echo $this->username;
    echo $this->password;
}

}

$obj = new Admin;
$obj->getHost();
?>
```

It's not initializing variables. Is there a good way to load credentials, other than that? I am creating a cms. I did some research like using ini file. But I think xml is most easiest.

Comment: Well, thanks. I keep that in ma mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not initializing variables.

I see two problems:

- `$this->crendentials` is an empty array. So your first `foreach` never runs.
- From the above and the contents of `$xml->children()`, the second `foreach` likely does nothing.

> Is there a good way to load credentials, other than that?

Leaving aside that you're loading credentials from an XML file, I'd suggest condensing the two `foreach` loops into one. Simply looping over the XML keys and assigning them to their respective class properties. That is to say drop `$this->crendentials`.